# Is there any short hand on formatting the String?

Tags: objective-c, programming-languages, syntax, formatting

I am using objective c, and I got some variables like this:

```
1100
920
845
1439
```

But I want to change it to :

```
11:00 
09:20
08:45
14:39
```

The problem is how can I fill the zero when I got three number only? I know the logic can be simple to do it I detect the string length, but is there any way to do it more effectually? Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
unsigned int time = 1100;

NSString *strTime = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02u:%02u", time / 100, time % 100];
```

Comment: To get leading zeroes, both of the `%d` s will need to be changed to `%02d`.

Comment: @David: Yeah I realised that the moment I answered.

Comment: what is the different between 02u and 02d?

Comment: @Ted Wong: `%u` is for *unsigned* integer decimal representation, whereas `%d` is for signed integer decimal representation.

Comment: time should be `unsigned int`.  NSUInteger is not guaranteed to be the right length for %u.

Comment: @JeremyP: You're right, I thought I saw an `iphone` tag in the question.